# Remove or hide my floating dialog activity from running app

Tags: android, hide, floating

I use this code for make my activity as dialog

```
       <activity
        android:name=".activity.popup"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
        tools:ignore="ExportedActivity">
       </activity>
```

and I start it like this

```
        Intent window = new Intent(mContext, popup.class);

        window.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);  
        mContext.startActivity(window);
```

and the result is

[image]

but why it's showing in running app ?

[image]

How can i remove it or hide it or any thing else prevent its from showing in running applications

Comment: prevent its from shown in running applications means your app only or any app?

Comment: @SohailZahid the dialog activity ! if you use facebook messenger its use dialog activity in chathead and its never shown in running application

Comment: so it means when your app is running them popup should not be shown otherwise it will be show. Right?

Comment: @SohailZahid i start my app and its shown on running app ok ... now start new dialog activity from service the dialog activity shown also in running application

Comment: from how many places you can start the service?

Comment: just one when start main activity .. and i make method check if service not running its will run service .. my problem on hide dialog activity from running application

Comment: there is contradiction in your statments you start a service from a button and the service shows a dailog and you want that dailog should not show when app is running but service is running only by just pressing a button then surely it will show when app it running button is pressed only when app is running.